# How does AppSurfer work? How to run Android OS on browser?

Tags: android-emulator

I recently got to know of this website [AppSurfer](http://www.appsurfer.com/) where they actually run Android OS in a web browser. It's interesting and also sleek.

How does this actually work?

Comment: may i know the possible reasons for down voting the question?

Answer (score 1):

The only clue I could find is from their website where they state

> Run Android Apps in the Browser
>
> Stream apps to any device or platform, on demand

So, it appears they use some sort of streaming technology where the App runs in an Android emulator instance running in their cloud and the content of the display is streamed to the clients browser.

That would mean that technically, Android does **not** run in the clients browser. The browser just acts as frontend to an (emulated I guess) Android instance.